# Asking question about Carrot and Stick strategy and mulltistage

Tags: game-theory

I am studying Game Theory and I have some confusions.

1. Is actually Carrot and Stick strategy is the same as Grim Trigger?
2. Is the Carrot and Stick only for Multistage game?
3. Can you please give me example of case using carrot and stick strategy?

I know that it's very basic questions but I am struggling to understand this topic.
Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't think "carrot and stick" is standard terminology in game theory. It would help if you would mention the source for this term.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker thank you for the reply. It's actually from my course at the university. I just found out that it's a term used as reward and punishment. For example, if we want to get higher payoff and if the game has multiple NEs, we can use the highest payoff strategy as carrot and the worse payoff from NE strategy as stick. It only works if only there is multiple NEs.

Comment: The logic of the argument occurs in many game theoretic  settings. There is a literature on finitely (!) repeated games that uses the logic, for example. But I think it is best to think of this as a general idea.